# How to do filter in VBA for the last three days?

Tags: vba, excel

I use VBA EXCEL and I need to to filter for row to the last 3 days.
For example: Today it's 02.11 and i dont want to see days 11.02, 10.02 and 09.02.

I tried to do this with the macro:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AB$11153").AutoFilter Field:=10, Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(2, "1/12/2016", 2, "1/13/2016", 2, "1/17/2016", 2, _
    "1/18/2016", 2, "1/20/2016", 2, "1/21/2016", 2, "1/22/2016", 2, "1/23/2016", 0, _
    "12/21/2015")
```

but its for spastic days and i need the last three days?

Comment: Do you want to see the LAST three days or DON'T see them?

Do you want to see the last 72 hours or the actually the last three days before today?

What's about using time ranges with the now-function ?

Answer (score 0):

The key to building criteria for the [AutoFilter method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844.aspx) is realizing that it must be a string. If you are comparing dates, the date that you supply must be in the same format as those that you are comparing against. Even a slight difference such as criteria posted as *m/d/yyyy* against values displayed as *mm/dd/yyyy* is sufficient to produce unreliable results.

```
With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        .Columns(10).AutoFilter Field:=1, _
            Criteria1:=Chr(62) & Format(Date - 3, .Cells(2, 10).NumberFormat)
    End With
End With
```

With this filter, we are constructing the date criteria using the cell formatting (e.g. [Range.NumberFormat property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196401.aspx)) found in the second row of the filtered column.